# Liquid error (snippets/backup-layout line 1): Could not find asset snippets/__default-template.liquid

Tags: shopify, liquid, liquid-template

I am using webflow to create an ecommerce theme and then converting it to a shopify theme using udesly.

I want to add a social login function for the ecommerce site (called bitbybit), bitbybit is displaying the login options correctly and even saves the new customer details within shopify's database. The problem I have is that once you select (for example) your google account/facebook acc/apple acc, the redirect takes me to a [www.mydomain.com/challenge](http://www.mydomain.com/challenge) page that gives this error code

```
Liquid error (snippets/backup-layout line 1): Could not find asset snippets/__default-template.liquid
```

I did manually add a file in the snippet folder (within the backend) named "__default-template.liquid" and it still doesnt seem to work, please assist

Answer (score 0):

The problem is something imports this as an asset so it looks in the assets folder not snippets

This is most likely what's happening:

```
{{ 'snippets/__default-template.liquid' | asset_url }}
```

And should be:

```
{% render '__default-template' %}
```